# How to edit Firefox's builtin HTML5 video player controls

Tags: html, firefox

Currently there is a global file loaded in Firefox `chrome://global/content/bindings/videocontrols.xml`, which has values for the things like seek time and playback rate for native HTML5 videos.

File can be found here: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/toolkit/content/widgets/videocontrols.xml

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1063314#answer-732595 Has a great post on how to edit this file and save it, but the link they provided (guide) is different from the original posting, so it's not easy to implement.

The file does contain:

```
case "accel-rightArrow": /* Seek forward 10% */
  oldval = this.video.currentTime;
  var maxtime = (this.video.duration || this.maxCurrentTimeSeen / 1000);
  if (keystroke == "rightArrow") {
    newval = oldval + 15;
  } else {
    newval = oldval + maxtime / 10;
  }
  this.video.currentTime = (newval &lt;= maxtime ? newval : maxtime);
```

Which can edited, but since it's somewhere in `/lib/` in a jar file, doesn't seem easily editable.

Is there a simple way, even in `about:config` to edit the native HTML5 videoplayer keybindings in Firefox?

Javascript Method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

This link provides information on how to control video player, so a possible user script is another option if changing videocontrols.xml is not viable.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Change the player controls?

Comment: Change the native Firefox HTML5 player navigation controls / values of the controls. Example is changing default seek from 15 seconds to 3 seconds.

Comment: Have you considered implementing your own custom controls, or is there some reason that forces you to use the native controls?

Comment: How would I go about implementing custom controls? Firefox controls seem to be hard compiled in. Would making a user script be the most viable option? This is to change the default HTML5 video player on all websites, not any that I control